# PHP BBCode and links

Tags: php, regex, anchor, bbcode

OK. So I am building a function that will parse a bbcoded string to html. The structure of the BBCode link is like so:

```
[url=http://somelink.com/]Link[/url]
```

And I want to make it:

```
<a href="http://somelink.com/">Link</a>
```

But I also want to check if the link is valid, to protect myself from XSS. I found this regex to check for valid link:

```
/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
```

And now, I tried to preg_match_all the $str and foreach match to check if it's url is valid and then to parse it to html, but it seems that I can't do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you try it ? What output/error do you get ?

Comment: You may find that one of the markdowns available around the web will pull all this out for you.

Github has a list of some.

http://github.github.com/github-flavored-markdown/

Comment: SoboLAN here is the piece of code:
$links = array();
        if(preg_match('/\[url=(.*)\](.*)\[\/url\]/', $str, $links))
        {
            echo '<pre>' . print_r($links, true) . '</pre>';
        }
It doesn't match what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP's built-in [Filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) module. It's available since PHP 5.2 and contains `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` constant to filter valid urls. See some [usage examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).

Never used this personally, but I believe relaying on language built-in capabilities is much safer than using regexes in your case (since you don't seem regex-proficient).

Comment: This isn't the problem I have.

Comment: I can't make the regex that replaces the BBCode to html and checks for valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Why re-invent the wheel?

You can use the [PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) to parse BBCode